How to create polygon with list of rings?
I've get several boost::geometry::model::rings stored in a vector (or list). I'm wondering is there any direct function that I can create a boost::geometry::model::polygon with these rings, with the first in the list as the exterior, and the rest as interiors? (I don't want to add points or rings one by one with iteration)
codes showing what I want:
#include<vector>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double> DPoint;
typedef bg::model::ring<DPoint, true> DRing;
typedef bg::model::polygon<DPoint, true> DPolygon;

using namespace std; 
int main(void)
{
    vector<DRing> rings = {outer, inner1, inner2, ...}; // more than 1 rings
    // I'm finding something like
    DPolygon pg(rings); 
    // or
    DPolygon pg(rings.begin(), rings.end()); 
    return 0; 
}


I've just came up with an idea like this:
DPolygon pg; 
pg.outer() = rings[0]; 
pg.inners() = vector<DRing>(++ rings.begin(), rings.end()); 

But I'm not sure whether the straight forward = will cause any trouble. At least I haven't found anything wrong in recent debugs.
